# react-query with useEffect resulting in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am new to react and  trying to call apis sequentially using react-query using the below code

I am planning on collecting all the responses together and then render the collected array , however my code is going in an **infinite loop** when i am trying to set the state within the useEffect block below

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUser[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [errors, setErros] = useState<IException[]>([]);

const queryResponses = userIds.map((userId) => {
    return useGetUser(userId); // calling useQuery internally 
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedUsers: IUser[] = [];
    const apiErrors: IException[] = [];
    let isApiLoading = false;
    queryResponses.map((response) => {
      if (response.isLoading) {
        isApiLoading = true;
      }
      response.isSuccess && fetchedUsers.push(response.data);
      response.isError && apiErrors.push(response.error);
    });
    fetchedUsers.length > 0 && setUsers(fetchedUsers);
    apiErrors.length > 0 && setErros(apiErrors);
    setIsLoading(isApiLoading);
  }, [queryResponses]);
```

when the queryResponses changes , the setUsers get called which again changes the queryResponses and its going in an infinite loop ..

Appreciate if anyone can help point out what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Not sure you can use a hook inside your queryResponses function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the useEffect whenever `queryResponses` changes. The problem is you are updating user data here
`fetchedUsers.length > 0 && setUsers(fetchedUsers);`, and `queryResponses` is pointing to `userIds.map` which means it's data has changed; this is what is causing this infinite loop.

**Solution**:
Make the `queryResponses` a useCallback function.
Something like this:

```js
const queryResponses = useCallback(() => {
  return userIds.map((userId) => {
    return useGetUser(userId);
  });
}, [])
```

Then call it in the useEffect. Like this.

```js
queryResponses().map((response) => {
   if (response.isLoading) {
      isApiLoading = true;
   }
   // your code...
```